# A Python method for calculating rolling Sum for a single line item and then using that to perform further calculations

Tags: python

Disclaimer: Python and Stack Overflow Noob here.

I have a data frame which looks like this below:

[image: ARRinput DataFrame]

And I need to calculate the annualized return rate for **each product** in that Data Frame using the formula:
**ARR = (Rolling 3 Month Sum of Returns) / (3 Month Moving Average of Field Population) X 100**

The question is:
In that DataFrame, the rolling sum of returns and the moving average of Field Population are wrong since, they are calculated for the entire data frame and not for each product. How do I make it calculate for each product?

Comment: Realized the image may not have posted correctly:

Comment: Edit your post, there is not image

Comment: something like itertools groupby, except for pandas?

Comment: @Kenny you mean [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)...?

Comment: Sorry. This could be a bad noob mistake - I tried doing `pd.DataFrame.groupby()` but ran into 
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-ad66535cc655> in <module>
----> 1 pd.DataFrame.groupby()

TypeError: groupby() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: You should edit that code into your question. People are probably ignoring this because you didn't post your attempt. You need to put that groupby call on the actual dataset. It looks like you're calling the underlying pandas class, not the data.